# Multiple lines in an Excel graph

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table:

| Time | Type | Usage1 [%] | Usage2 [%] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-09 09:00 DST | LG1 | 60.0581 | 87.4926 |
| 2021-07-09 09:00 DST | LG2 | 42.1409 | 40.57 |
| 2021-07-09 09:00 DST | LG3 | 63.433 | 49.9326 |
| 2021-07-09 10:00 DST | LG1 | 53.6577 | 86.6658 |
| 2021-07-09 10:00 DST | LG2 | 36.384 | 41.7439 |
| 2021-07-09 10:00 DST | LG3 | 54.5699 | 54.0306 |
| 2021-07-10 09:00 DST | LG1 | 35.2818 | 75.8487 |
| 2021-07-10 09:00 DST | LG2 | 34.101 | 37.7934 |
| 2021-07-10 09:00 DST | LG3 | 50.4009 | 46.8263 |
| 2021-07-10 10:00 DST | LG1 | 39.3575 | 78.3179 |
| 2021-07-10 10:00 DST | LG2 | 50.3955 | 43.3913 |
| 2021-07-10 10:00 DST | LG3 | 52.2898 | 51.8793 |
| 2021-07-11 09:00 DST | LG1 | 36.8559 | 71.9565 |
| 2021-07-11 09:00 DST | LG2 | 31.1939 | 35.8108 |
| 2021-07-11 09:00 DST | LG3 | 44.6744 | 49.5196 |
| 2021-07-11 10:00 DST | LG1 | 43.9611 | 74.5974 |
| 2021-07-11 10:00 DST | LG2 | 39.075 | 36.9884 |
| 2021-07-11 10:00 DST | LG3 | 41.0939 | 45.0962 |

I want the x-axis to be Time, and then plot a line in the graph for Usage1 and Usage2 for each Type.
So in total, since there are 3 different Types, there should be a total of 6 lines.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: As you're updating your question to include what you've tried and, possibly, a mockup of what you want the results to look like, try making a pivot table with a pivot chart based on it.

Comment: had u tried [ select all > (press) F11 > Design : chg chart type : Line graph ] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you insert a pivot table chart as following. Drag the "Type" field into Legend (Series) section.

[image]